# When adding translations in twig, is the source language always English?

Tags: i18n-l10n

When adding translatable strings in Twig templates, is it assumed that the string is always written in English and then translated to other languages? Even if there is a different 'base' language or only one (non English) language used on the site?

I've been scouring various docs pages and [this is the only time](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Language%21language.api.php/group/i18n/10) I've come across anything stating this explicitly:

> UI text is always put into code and related files in English.

and:

> Because the source of translation strings is English, and some words...